# How can I add filter to Completion Suggester in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Does anyone know how to add filter to suggester?

This works very well:

```
{
  "headline-suggest": {
    "text": "n",
    "completion": {
      "field": "headline_suggest"
    }
  }
}
```

But I want force ElasticSearch to build list of suggestions from subset of data, like:

```
{
  "headline-suggest": {
    "text": "n",
    "completion": {
      "field": "headline_suggest"
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "mydifferentfield": "someword"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I achieve it?

(I'm using Elasticsearch 0.90.5)

Comment: Can you post your solution or accept a answer?

Answer (score 23):

As per version 1.2.0, you can add context to your suggester and obtain filtered suggestions.

<s>[Introductory blog post](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-1-2-adding-context-suggestions)</s>
[Introductory blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-1-2-adding-context-suggestions)

<s>[Full Docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html)</s>
[Full Docs](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html)

Answer (score 1):

i am not really sure about that, but i think that you can not filter a suggest request in elasticsearch.

from what i read this is due to the kind of data structure it is stored in. elasticsearch calculates statistical data on the terms to suggest at index time and uses those for the suggest operations.

did you try performing a normal query in combination with a suggest? maybe there is a different outcome to that?

```
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search' -d '{
  "query" : {
    ...
  },
  "suggest" : {
    ...
  }
}'
```

Comment: No filters supported. An FST is built in memory and kept up-to-date at index time, no way to filter out suggestions at query time.

Comment: that's kind of what i remember.

Comment: Filters are now supported using `context` suggesters. https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-1-2-adding-context-suggestions

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to filter on your completion. 
As javanna said, Completion feature is built on FST at indexing time, so you couldn't use filter here.

To do it, you could play around with ngram/edge ngram.
Let read here to get basic idea: http://jontai.me/blog/2013/02/adding-autocomplete-to-an-elasticsearch-search-application/