# How to apply filter on Elasticsearch completion suggester

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field in my schema let say account_id and for completion suggester in elasticsearch I want to apply filter on that particular field.

Comment: already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434811/how-can-i-add-filter-to-completion-suggester-in-elasticsearchhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434811/how-can-i-add-filter-to-completion-suggester-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: link not working